# setting ViewModel classes (from DLL) not to be mapped with EF?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

My custom types (Poco) are coming form a class library DLL. Same class library has ViewModels, I don't want to map ViewModels with EF and database. I know to avoid mapping of a property we can use `[NotMapped]` attribute in code but in current situation I don't have code and classes are coming form DLL.

Please guide me how I can tell EF not to map certain classes.

Answer (score 3):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) the `NotMapped` attribute:

> Denotes that a **property** or **class** should be excluded from database mapping.

Use the `NotMapped` attribute at the class level. For example:

```
[NotMapped]
public class MyPocoModel
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I m sorry I couldn't clarify it, classes are coming form a complited DLL. Please see my edit and kindly guide.

Comment: Do you have your classes mapped in your context class?